# Segmentation fault (11) when using malloc inside a function to form a string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, malloc, c-strings

I'm trying to use a function to assign space and fill that space (or at least some of it) with characters to form a string. Within the function I make a call to malloc, and within the same function I assign characters to the given space. The following code gives the general gist of what I'm doing:

```
#define INITIAL 10

int func(char **s);

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *s;
    int n;

    n = func(&s);
    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}

int
func(char **s) {
    int i;

    *s = (char*)malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char));
    assert(*s);

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("i=%d\n", i);
        *s[i] = 'a'; /*'a' is an arbitrary char for this example */  
    }
    return i;    
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
i=0
i=1
i=2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The reason I have my function return an int is because I ultimately want the function to return the length of the string I have formed.
I'm completely unsure why I am getting a segmentation fault; it seems I have assigned enough space to fit the next char in. It also seems weird to me that it stops at i=2.
If anyone could identify the mistakes I have made I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can't you use [strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) or [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (on Linux, you could)? Don't forget to compile your code with all warnings & debug ino (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)...). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/); avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: You should add `free(s);` before `return 0;` or your program will create a memory leak

Comment: Curious: what suggest using `*sizeof(char)` in `malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char))` as `sizeof(char)` is always 1?  Nice: alternative: `*s = malloc(INITIAL* sizeof *(*s));`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
*s[i] = 'a';
```

you want

```
(*s)[i] = 'a';
```

`*s[i]` is equivalent to `*(s[i])`.  That is, it treats s as an array of strings and gives you the first character of the string at index i.

Comment: Thanks a lot! All fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

`*s[i]` first calculate `s[i]`, which won't be valid place for `i!=0`, then dereference it and try to put `'a'` there. It may cause Segmentation Fault.

Try changing `*s[i]` to `(*s)[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Postfix `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*s[i]` is being parsed as `*(s[i])`, which isn't what you want; you want to dereference `s` and index into the result, so you need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `s`: `(*s)[i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot John, appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `size_t` instead of an int. Or `ssize_t` if you need the function to return a negative value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INITIAL 10

ssize_t func(char **);

int main(void)
{
    char *s;

    if((func(&s)) == -1)
    {
        printf("An error occurred\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Done\n");

    free(s);
    return 0;
}


ssize_t func(char **s)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    if ( INITIAL < 1 )
            return -1;

    if (!(*s = malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(char))))
            return -1;

    for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
        printf("i=%zu\n", i);
        (*s)[i] = 'a';; /*'a' is an arbitrary char for this example */
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Note: `ssize_t` is not defined in standard C.  Common extension though.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what would be the benefit of doing this? I'm fairly new to C and my textbook only briefly mentions size_t, and doesn't specify how it is different to int.